# adding a close icon if active and removing it if not active

Tags: javascript, jquery

need help in removing the "close" icon if not active

[code i have](http://jsfiddle.net/606pm4z2/)

```
    $("#mason2 li div").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide().appendTo("#mason2").fadeIn(200);
    $(this).append('<p class="close">[close]</p>'); 
    if (
        $(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');              
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().hide().prependTo("#mason2").fadeIn(200);           
    }   
    });
```

and just noticed it keeps repeating the append everytime its clicked

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add and delete the close icon you can insert it in all the li tags, then you can use css to show and hide it when the li is active

See example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ekc0q6g/1/)

**Script**

```
$("#mason2 li div").click(function() {
    $("#mason2 li.active").appendTo("#mason2").fadeIn(200);
    $("#mason2 li.active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    $(this).parent().hide().prependTo("#mason2").fadeIn(200);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#mason2 {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

.close{
    color: red;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: none;
}

.active .close {
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mason2">                        
    <li><div class="rep">1111111</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">22222222</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">3333333</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">44444444</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">55555555</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">666666666</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">7777777</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
    <li><div class="rep">88888</div><p class="close">[close]</p></li>
</ul>
```